# How to show text when certain time comes

Tags: python, android, time, countdown

How to show text when certain time comes

Such as when the time to 0:30:0 will display the text

```
import time

def countdown(time_sec):

    time_msec = time_sec*10

    while time_msec:

        mins, secs = divmod(time_msec, 600)

        secs, msecs = divmod(secs, 10)

        timeformat = "{:02d}:{:02d}.{:01d}".format(mins, secs, msecs)

        print(timeformat, end='\r')

        time.sleep(1/10)

        time_msec -= 1

    print("stop")

countdown(61)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can eliminate that remote possibility of 'skipping' by making clock independent. A modified version of @fallouthase :

```
import datetime
import time

target_seconds = 30

def print_str(time):
    if time==target_seconds:
        print("Its time")

def time_call(time):   
    print(current_seconds)
    
while True:
    current_seconds = datetime.datetime.now().time().second
    time_call(current_seconds)
    print_str(current_seconds)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

I can show you an example I coded some time ago, which displays a message every time the clocl hits 30 seconds.

```
import datetime
import time

# set the target time to 30 seconds
target_seconds = 30


while True:
    # get the current time in seconds
    current_seconds = datetime.datetime.now().time().second

    # check if the current time matches the target time
    if current_seconds == target_seconds:
        print("It's time!")

    # wait for 1 second before checking the time again
    time.sleep(1)
```

you should be able to adapt it for your needs. Basically you do an if cluase that checks if your target time has come.

Comment: Note that if the loop ends up running slow enough (e.g. because the computer is doing too much else) that it skips over the 30-second mark, it will end up missing that instance.